# Using erb template and sidekiq

Tags: sinatra, erb, sidekiq

I'm using sinatra and sidekiq together.  I'm trying to render a erb template from within a sidekiq worker and i'm getting a undefined method 'erb'.  In my head, things should work cause sidekiq is loaded up as an instance of my sinatra app, so it should have the erb method.  What am i missing here?

```
class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    erb(:emailTemplate)
  end
end
```

(i now realized the SomeWorker class has nothing to to do with sinatra and so of course it doesn't have the erb method.  maybe i can just make a call out to helper module? in place of the erb method call?)

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out 1 solution:

```
require 'erb'
require 'tilt'

class ForgotEmailWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    template = tilt.new(__path_to_erb_file).render
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a workaround you can try:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    template_path = 'path/to/template.erb'
    template_content = File.read(template_path

    erb_template = ERB.new(template_content)
    result = erb_template.result(binding)
    puts result
  end
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).